# Add or update an edge in Gremlin

Tags: gremlin, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I have a graph database in Azure CosmoDB that stores how similar vertices are and the edge contains the numeric value of how similar they are.

The complication is that I want to add an edge or update by incrementing the similarity value. This is the current code I have for adding:

```
g.V('A').addE('similar').to(g.V('B')).property('x', 10)
```

I need something that will increase X if the edge exists, or create it if not. Pseudo code exemplifying it:

```
g.V('A').updateE('similar').to(g.V('B')).property('x', currentValue+2).ifNulll({g.V('A').addE('similar').to(g.V('B')).property('x', 10)})
```

is there an easy way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [known recipe](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/#element-existence) for checking existence by using the pattern `fold().coalesce(unfold()...)` for vertex and similar pattern for edge. In your case, you want to update a property value as well.

Assuming there are vertices with IDs `A` and `B`, and edge goes from `A-->B`, the query might look like this:

```
g.withSack(0).V('B').as('toV').V('A').coalesce(
    outE('similar').where(inV().as('toV')),
    addE('similar').to('toV').property('similarity', 0)
)
.sack(assign).by('similarity').sack(sum).by(constant(2))
.property('similarity', sack())
```

**Explanation:**

Get B (target) vertex and save reference, get A (source) vertex.

Using `coalesce`, check if there is an edge connecting them, otherwise create such edge and set similarity to 0.

Assign the 'similarity' value to the `sack`, and sum the additional value.

Last, store the new value on the edge property.

**Another query without using `sack`:**

```
g.V('B').as('toV').V('A').coalesce(
    outE('similar').where(inV().as('toV')),
    addE('similar').to('toV').property('similarity', 0)
).property('similarity', values('similarity').fold(10, sum))
```

Comment: the creation of edges if they don't exist is working, but the adding to the similarity value is not:
Unable to resolve symbol 'assign' in the current context. @ line 1, column 156.
Unable to resolve symbol 'sum' in the current context. @ line 1, column 186.
Unable to resolve symbol 'sack' in the current context.
might be due to an older version of Gremlin in CosmoDb

Comment: I also tried .property('similarity', union(values('similarity'), constant(1.0)).sum()), as recommended in another StackOverflow question, but it throws error 'Cannot create ValueField on non-primitive type GraphTraversal.'

Comment: I don't have CosmosDB environment to check. I've updated the answer with another query that don't use sack().